# Aggregate surefire reports of maven project hierarchy as XML for eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a project hierarchy which built with maven. How can I run all the tests in the whole hierarchy at once from eclipse and easily go to the failures?

The [maven surefire plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/index.html) spews loads of output at the console, but it is tiresome to find the failures there. It also generates XML report files which I can easily open within the normal eclipse JUnit view - but these are many many files and it is difficult to find the files of the failed tests. The [maven surefire report plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/index.html) allows to aggregate all test results with `mvn surefire-report:report-only -Daggregate=true` but only in HTML format. What I'd love to have is an aggregation of all test results in the eclipse JUnit view - just as I get if I use "Run as JUnit-Test".

(Ideally, I would start all the unittests with "Run as JUnit-Test", but I can do that only for one project, not for all the projects in the workspace.)