# Maven Junit Aggregate Xml

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm looking to aggregate the junit report xml files generated from maven running junit tests.  I found the below and added it to my pom.  But I believe this is only for the report, whereas I want the xml files to be aggregated.

https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/report-only-mojo.html

I have the following in my POM

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.21.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <parallel>methods</parallel>
        <threadCount>10</threadCount>
        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                <aggregate>true</aggregate>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But it is generating multiple test reports.

I also tried [Aggregate surefire reports of maven project hierarchy as XML for eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20884672/aggregate-surefire-reports-of-maven-project-hierarchy-as-xml-for-eclipse) but this doesn't work either.  But again I believe this is only for the report.

Any ideas?  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You have used maven-surefire-plugin instead of maven-surefire-report-plugin. Try with maven-surefire-report-plugin